# How do I render Python plots in RMarkdown?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown

For the life of me, I can't get to render plots in RMarkdown using Python. The plots display in my Python Editor, but not when I switch to RStudio trying to build a PDF/HTML report. I've been all over the internet, everyone has an answer, but none has the solution to my issue. Here's the error message I get the attached error below:

[image]

Below I made up some data to show what I'm trying to achieve. Once the application hits the seaborn line it produces the attached error message in RStudio

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
```

Importing Required Packages

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import uniform  # for training-and-test split
import statsmodels.api as sm  # statistical models (including regression)
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf  # R-like model specification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # 2D plotting
import seaborn as sns
```

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 20)
y = np.random.normal(0, 2, 20)
sns.scatterplot(x, y)
```

Comment: Hard to help without a reproducible example of the (R) code that generates the error. Could you show us your .Rmd?

Comment: @M.A. I added the .Rmd partial code. Basically the line that causes that error message is the plot, not necessarily seaborn, any other plotting call would produce the same error message.

Comment: Sorry but that’s not what I meant by reproducible. The python code is fine. Seeing the markdown file could help, but I think this issue is caused by a missing dll.

Comment: @M. A. The first 2 lines are all that there is as far as Rmd is concerned. Everything else past that point is all Python. Again, if I remove the plotting functions the code works fine. Also, you might be right everything I saw on other forums mentions ".dll"  but none says specifically what they are called, where to download them or where they should go in respect to R or Python installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/matplotlib-inline-plots-with-reticulate-on-rstudio-server/16357)

All I needed was to add these two lines in the R setup chunk below the `library(reticulate)` call

```
matplotlib <- import("matplotlib")
matplotlib$use("Agg", force = TRUE)
```